# Setting fix bone length

Tags: bones

How can I fix the length of each bone to 140mm.

[image]

---

Thank you for you're comment.

I have still the following problem:

When I adjust a bone on the Y-axis with a length of 140mm and I rotate the head to the X-Axis the length is scaled to 105mm. What I'am doing wrong.

[image: Length 140mm]

[image: Length scaled to 105mm]

Comment: you could use a mesh with 3 edges of 140, then use them to snap your bones, but maybe it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: It seems that your rotation X axis is not exactly the bone's X axis. You can rotate exactly in needed plane if you align the view with one of the sides of the bone. With bone selected, press Shift+(Num1|Num7|Num3) [and also Ctrl to see the opposite side]. then just press R to rotate. In pose mode a bone rotates around its head, but in the edit mode you can set the 3d cursor to the head (Shift+S, Cursor to selected), and use it as the pivot point for rotation. In this case the bone's length will stay unchanged during rotations.

Answer (score 1):

In the edit mode in the N panel you have boxes, where you can enter the exact locations for the bone tail and its head. In your case you can align the bone to any axis, then enter desired offset of the tail (or the head). Then you can change the bone rotation (R) without affecting its scale, and not moving its head or tail separately. If you need a bunch of bones with exact length you can set the length for one large bone, then subdivide it with needed numbers of subdivisions, or you can use the duplicate command (Shift+D) for the bone which length is already set. To snap bones to each other, you can select entire bone (not just head or tail), and use snapping to 3D cursor (Shift+S).